# Store output of a script run over ssh in a variable

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting

I'm trying to capture output of a script (resides on a remote server) run over SSH into a variable, below is my code:

```
ssh username@hostname << EOF
variable=`./script_on_remote_server.sh`
echo $variable
EOF
```

When i run the above script, nothing gets stored in the variable and echo of that variable returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by showing one way of achieving this:

```
variable=`echo ./script_on_remote_server.sh | ssh username@hostname`
```

Or if you're using bash, I prefer this syntax:

```
variable=$(echo ./script_on_remote_server.sh | ssh username@hostname)
```

It's a little difficult to tell from your post, but it looks like you were trying to do the following:

```
ssh username@hostname <<EOF
variable=./script_on_remote_server.sh
echo $variable
EOF
```

However, there are a few misunderstandings here. `variable=command` is not the correct syntax for assigning the output of the command to a variable; in fact, it doesn't even run the command, it merely assigns the literal value `command` to `variable`. What you want is `` variable=`command` `` or (in bash syntax) `variable=$(command)`. Also, I presume that your goal is to have `variable` available to the shell on the local machine. Declaring `variable` in code to be run on the remote machine is not the way to do that. ;) Even if you did this:

```
ssh username@hostname <<EOF
variable=`./script`
echo $variable
EOF
```

This is just a less efficient way of running the command on the remote host as usual, because `variable` gets lost immediately:

```
echo ./script | ssh username@hostname
```

Also, note that the `ssh` command accepts a command to run as an additional argument, so you can abbreviate the whole thing to:

```
variable=`ssh username@hostname ./script_on_remote_server`
```

Answer (score 1):

For `./script_on_remote_server.sh` to be evaluated in the remote machine. You'll need to quote `<< EOF` with `<< 'EOF'` and add `-T` to your `ssh` command.

```
ssh -T username@hostname << 'EOF'
variable=`./script_on_remote_server.sh`
echo $variable
EOF
```